# SnowparkFetchDataException: (1406): Failed to fetch a Pandas Dataframe. The error is: Found non-unique column index

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While running some code like this:

```py
  session = ...
    return session.table([DB,SCHEMA, MANUAL_METRICS_BY_SIZE]).select("TECHNOLOGY","OBJECTTYPE","OBJECTTYPE","SIZE","EFFORT").to_pandas()
```

I got this error.

Any idea of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well it was easier that what I thought.

I had a duplicated column name and pandas doesn't like that.

Just check your columns. For example with df.columns and remove the duplicated column